# list(y) behavior is "wrong" on first call

Tags: python, list, iterator

I have an iterator with a `__len__` method defined. Questions:

If you call list(y) and y has a `__len__` method defined, then `__len__` is called.

1) Why?

In my output, you will see that the len(list(y)) is 0 on the first try.  If you look at the list output, you will see that on the first call, I receive an empty list, and on the second call I receive the "correct" list.

2) Why is it returning a list of length zero at all?

3) Why does the list length correct itself on all subsequent calls?

Also notice that calling "enumerate" is not the issue. Class C does the same thing but using a while loop and calls to next().

Code:

```
showcalls = False

class A(object):
    _length = None
    def __iter__(self):
        if showcalls:
            print "iter"
        self.i = 0
        return self        
    def next(self):
        if showcalls:
            print "next"
        i = self.i + 1
        self.i = i
        if i > 2:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            return i

class B(A):
    def __len__(self):
        if showcalls:
            print "len"
        if self._length is None:
            for i,x in enumerate(self):
                pass
            self._length = i
            return i
        else:
            return self._length

class C(A):
    def __len__(self):
        if showcalls:
            print "len"
        if self._length is None:
            i = 0
            while True:
                try:
                    self.next()
                except StopIteration:
                    self._length = i
                    return i
                else:
                    i += 1
        else:
            return self._length

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    print len(list(a)), len(list(a)), len(list(a))
    print
    b = B()
    print len(list(b)), len(list(b)), len(list(b))
    print
    c = C()
    print len(list(c)), len(list(c)), len(list(c))
```

Output:

```
2 2 2

0 2 2

0 2 2
```

Comment: You don't need to define the `__len__` method for every iterator. For example, you can iterate over files, but a file object has no `__len__`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If you call list(y) and y has a
>   **len** method defined, then **len** is called.  why?

Because it's faster to build the resulting list with the final length, if known from the start, than to begin with an empty list and append one item at a time.  And `__len__` is, and must be, 100% guaranteed to be reliable.

IOW, do **not** implement special methods like `__len__` if and when you can't return a reliable value.

As for the second question, your implementations of `__len__` are broken because they **consume** the iterator (and don't return it to its pristine state) -- so they leave no items for following `.next` calls, so the `list` constructor gets a `StopIteration` and decides that your `__len__` was just flaky (it's unfortunately flakier than poor `list` can guess...!-).

Comment: So if I set i back equal to zero in my `__len__` function, that should do the trick.  

Note: This is actually coming from a class that wraps around a file containing multi-line items.  So I don't know the number of items in the file until I scan it once (unfortunately there is no header information in the file that tells me this).

Comment: @PyProg, yep, making sure your `__len__` is "idempotent" (fancy talk for: won't alter the object's state if called repeatedly) is a good rule of thumb!